# Sort Months PowerBI Designer

Tags: sorting, date-sorting, powerbi

I am trying to sort months into PowerBI Designer Preview, it looks like it only can be done alphabetically. But when I look on the internet at images of PowerBI it looks like they are all sorted correctly. Can somebody help me? And there must be other people who are facing this problem right?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Power Pivot, you can set a sort by column. This hints Power Pivot to sort a given column like a column of month names by another column like a column of integers representing the order of month names.  The pattern is to create a Date table - a table with all of your dates.  In this date table you create a column with month names and another column with month indexes. Then you select the column with month names and set the sort by property to the month indexes column.  Usually, I like to create a 'MonthYear' column that has values like "Dec-14", "Jan-15" etc. this then allows me to sort correctly across years.

Answer (score 1):

Check what is the data type of the column you are trying to sort. If it's Text then it would sort alphabetically, irrespective that these are numbers. Make sure it's Date or Number to sort correctly.